# EF Core 3.1 select specific column and update it

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a table Client with two dozens of column and I need to update only one column. Instead of loading the entire row I am loading the column that I need to update, I update the value and then call SaveChanges(). Column is not updated. Below is my code:

```
public async Task DeleteClients(IEnumerable<long> clientIds)
{
    var dbClients = await (from client in dbContext.Client
                           where clientIds.Contains(client.Id)
                           select new Client
                           {
                               Id = client.Id,
                               ClientStatusId = client.ClientStatusId
                           }).ToListAsync();

    dbClients.ForEach(dbClient =>
    {
        dbClient.ClientStatusId = (int)ClientStatusEnum.Deleted;
    });

    await unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
}
```

Can anyone suggests why it is not updating since I am not using NoTracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone suggests why it is not updating

Because you don't `select` `Client` entities, but merely *project* to `Client` objects (so-called *stubs*). Projected objects, even of entity types, aren't attached to the context. For example, you could easily create clients without key values. Automatically attaching them would attach them as `Added`, which is not what you want.

So you have to attach the clients explicitly:

```cs
    ...

    dbContext.Client.AttachRange(dbClients);

    dbClients.ForEach(dbClient =>
    {
        dbClient.ClientStatusId = (int)ClientStatusEnum.Deleted;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. However calling attach how does it find if the entry was changed. I dont see any extra call in the database to get original values.

Comment: That's what attaching does. Now EF is able to track changes. You get the essential original values from the database.

Comment: I understood that. But how does it track the changes if it does not have the original values? I dont see any extra call to get original values

Comment: That's your first query. EF knows `ClientStatusId` and detects that it's changed.

Comment: What about the other columns that I dont receive initially. In the new entry (one that I just select two columns) they are null. Shouldn't be those updated then with null values?

Comment: No, because you only change one value. EF marks individual properties as Modified.

Comment: ah ok. Because I was under the impression that I had to explicitly set specific column that it was modified. So it keeps track what was selected and checks only those.

Comment: I am doing this to optimize performance (not select all the columns). By calling Attach isn't it slower than select all columns and not call AttachRange?

Comment: No, I think working with stub entities for updating just one (or a few) attributes is a good idea and `AttachRange` is a quick way to get entities attached.

Comment: I noticed that calling AttachRange after the property is updated doesn't do anything. Does the order really matters?

Comment: Yes, when the entities are attached, EF stores the values they have *at that moment* as original values.

Comment: Now I get it. You have to call it first to start tracking and then update. Great. Thanks a lot man